# email with php BCC and To relations and also spam issue

Tags: php, email

i am having a issue with sending emails with cronjobs.
actually i need to send email to all the recently joined users
and so the emails are something like $to='acx1@xyz.com,acx2@xyz.com,acx3@xyz.com';

here i need to send the mail to all the receipts but not to let them know that i have sent this mail to all these persons in receipt basically BCC them

but the problem is that if i put the $to into BCC then what should i put in to function of mail

if to is empty then it may be spamed

i want to send this mail to all the receipts but when they check the headers they should see their email only

and one more issue please let me know if i am using correct headers ?
because sometimes my email is spammed by gmail

```
   $from='tests.com';
   $to='contact@test.com';
   $message="<body> some html data with inline css </body>"

  $subject="Hii this is test";
  $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: $from <contact@test.com>" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: contact@test.com" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'BCC:   acx1@xyz.com,acx2@xyz.com,acx3@xyz.com' . "\r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Run a loop. Send one email per address

Comment: it may not be good because if i have about 30 users then the loop will run 30 times and send 30 individual emails. and if i send BCC then only one email does the job

Comment: no the loop is the recommended way, i do it with thousands of emails

Comment: ok thankyou sir @Dagon :), 
only last thing is there any thing you can suggest me about spam actually my emails are spammed i dont know why ? 
server ip may be a problem ??